# Database with good compression so it results in an extremely small file

Tags: database, sqlite

I am looking to store data from my program in a database but it's important that the data size is extremely small; I do not care much about read or write speed as long as it's less than 30 seconds and I can still read specific rows of the database. I have looked at using sqlite3 however it doesn't really do compression so I was wondering if there was an alternative that produced smaller files and met the rest of my requirements.

Edit:

I'm intending to use the data via a CLI that when given a string returns the corresponding array of strings. e.g. Searching 'Cat' would return ["cats.com","cattery.co.uk"] in the same way that you would call it from a python dictionary. I'm either going to use C or Python for the program and I'm fine with the licensing as long as it's not commercial in any way and can be used in an MIT licensed application.